# AX2012 - How to unlink business logic from report?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm creating a new SSRS report in AX2012. At first, I added some Data Methods through Visual Studio, but later I found another way to get what I wanted without using those data methods. Consequently, I deleted the Data Methods and the Business Logic project.

Now, everytime I build the report, I get a warning :

> Could not resolve 'projectname' from the AOT. If the reference is required in your code, you may get compilation errors.

How do I delete the reference to the business logic project? My report runs without problems, but I would like to stop getting this warning...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be a project dependency.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx

To remove:

> In Solution Explorer, select a project. On the Project menu, choose
>   Project Dependencies. The Project Dependencies dialog box opens. On
>   the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down
>   menu. In the Depends on field, clear the check boxes beside any other
>   projects that are no longer dependencies of this project.

EDIT: Another option is to export the XPO and edit it in there, and reimport.

Comment: When I try to uncheck the box, I get the message: "This dependency was added by the project system and cannot be removed"

Comment: I also tried manually editing the .dynamicsproj in Notepad, but there's no mention of the dependant project in this file...

Comment: How about just exporting the SSRS XPO and editing it there?  Or re-creating it by importing?

Comment: Thank you, exporting, modifying and reimporting the XPO did the trick!

Comment: I accepted your answer, but the answer actually is in the comments... Should you update your answer, or post another answer, so I can accept the right one for my problem? Or since they're linked, you don't need to?